# How to loop through listBox and remove words before a certain character?

Tags: c#, for-loop, listbox

How would I use a for loop to go through a listBox and remove words before a certain character?

For example if my listBox contains items resembling the following:

```
','ae5e87df42fa5921
```

And I want to remove everything before the `','` how would I do so with each item in the listBox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a for loop you can simply call `item = item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf("','"))`
Like so:

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
lb.Items.Add("12341','2341");
lb.Items.Add("123415','112341");
lb.Items.Add("543225','11234134");
for (int i = 0; i < lb.Items.Count; i++) {
    string item = lb.Items[i] as string;
    item = item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf("','"));
    lb.Items[i] = item;
}
```

**Edit:**
Here you have full example, which works. Just add the ListBox and the button, and assign the event to it's `Click` handler:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        lb.Items.Add("12341','2341");
        lb.Items.Add("123415','112341");
        lb.Items.Add("543225','11234134");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lb.Items.Count; i++) {
            string item = lb.Items[i] as string;
            item = item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf("','"));
            lb.Items[i] = item;
        }
    }
}
```

It **IS** working.

Comment: The text wasn't replaced :/

Comment: @EdwinTorres Then you've done something wrong. I've edited my post - there you have full example, you can create a new form and replace it's code with the edited one.

Comment: Hey I added this item to a listbox: 543225','11234134 and added the code to a button. When I run it the item is now: ','11234134  not 11234134 how I want it.